# How to create IONIC component for intl-tel-input in IONIC 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

How to create IONIC 3 component for https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input ?
or there is any other Module in ionic 3 for that 
 I would appreciate any help.

Comment: If you thinkg provided answer solved your problem then you can accept answer so that others will get benefit out it, thanks :)

Comment: there is no solution until now :(

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use alternative **[ng2-tel-input](https://github.com/gauravsoni119/ng2-tel-input)**, Because the library which you trying to use is written Javascript which will you need to write a wrapper and that makes something hard to implement.

So here is solution to use ng2-tel-input

**Step 1:** Install library `npm install ng2-tel-input --save`

**Step 2:** Import style `@import 'intl-tel-input/build/css/intlTelInput.css';`

**Step 3:** Import module `import {Ng2TelInputModule} from 'ng2-tel-input';`

**Step 4** Add `ng2TelInput` directive to your text field

```
<input type="text"
  ng2TelInput
  [ng2TelInputOptions]="{initialCountry: 'in'}"
  (hasError)="hasError($event)"
  (ng2TelOutput)="getNumber($event)"
  (intlTelInputObject)="telInputObject($event)"
  (countryChange)="onCountryChange($event)" />
```

**Step 5:** get User enter number in ionic page

```
telInputObject(obj) {
    console.log(obj);
    obj.intlTelInput('setCountry', 'in');
  }
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Can't bind to 'ng2TelInputOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Comment: have you imported  Ng2TelInputModule in your page module

Comment: Yes until now there is no sulution !! anybody here workeed with this module in ionic 3 ?  NeeeeD Help

Answer (score 1):

If you receive the error "Can't bind to 'ng2TelInputOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'input'". In particular, for Ionic.

There are two ways to solve this:

1. If you are **lazy loading** the component / page by importing the module rather than the component:

   - Add `Ng2TelInputModule` to imports in the module of that component / page
2. If you are importing the component / page directly in a module (**not lazy  loading**)

   - Add `Ng2TelInputModule` to imports to the module that contains the imported page / component
   - Add `Ng2TelInputModule` to imports of the page / component's module

For example, if you are importing the component / page in app.module.ts under declarations, you need to follow step 2.

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote a simple package for this to sue in one of my projects. Just for future if someone else finds them in similar situation. Here is the link:
[ion-intl-tel-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ion-intl-tel-input)